# Celery task subprocesses fill up concurrency slots?

Tags: python, django, concurrency, subprocess, celery

I am running a series of long-running heavy-weight Celery tasks (which spawn multiple subprocesses) in a queue with `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 4`. Initially, 4 tasks are started as they should. However, as tasks finish no new tasks are started until more finish and soon Celery keeps the amount of active tasks down to 1 or 2 until all tasks are complete (confirmed by Celery Flower).

When I only run simple tasks such as the default Celery `add` function everything works as expected.

Does the subprocesses started by Celery tasks (with same process group ID as the task) count to fill up the concurrency slots? Is there any way to make sure Celery only counts the tasks themselves?

Comment: I had similar problems, are you using eventlet/gevent? How many queues to you have?

Comment: @RafaelBarros I am using a single queue, and not eventlet/gevent.

Comment: Try reading this to see if it makes any sense: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html

Comment: @RafaelBarros That sound very interesting. However, _"but you need to ensure your tasks do not perform blocking calls"_ makes it impractical, because all my subprocesses use `subprocess.communicate()` and changing that is not possible in my case.

Comment: Thats where queues fall in place, if you could split your tasks without the subprocess.communicate into a queue that is running with eventlet, you could take some advantage in part of your tasks. Otherwise, I don't see how to fix this without removing the blocking call. I believe that prefork (the default for celery) is considering every subprocess call another "fork" thus, not allowing multiple tasks to run simultaneously.

Comment: @RafaelBarros Thank you. Another option (not really a solution, though) would be to set `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 8` as the tasks mostly have exactly one subprocess running. This would therefore work all times except for in the beginning when 8 tasks are started. Do you know if there is a way to limit the tasks in the beginning? Would the `rate_limit` be able to achieve that?

Comment: that is beyond my knowledge, but reading the docs, it might work. If you try it, please, refer back to me. I'll add an answer with a summary of the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery uses prefork as the default execution pool, and every time you spawn a subprocess (another fork), it counts up to the number of concurrent processes running, i.e. the number in `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY`.

The way to avoid this are by using [eventlet](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html), which will allow you to spawn multiple async calls on each task, as long as your tasks don't have any calls that block, like the `subprocess.communicate`.

To further optimize, you can try splitting the tasks that use subprocess.communicate into a different queue that has a worker using prefork and everything else that is doesn't block in a worker with eventlet.